# product title is different in the cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I finished adding a product to my woo commerce and the titles show the name of each product correctly, however, when I add the products to the cart, in the cart the title shows a different name of the product. it seems like, when I duplicated products, the title of the first item is still there. but it is only incorrect in "View cart".

Comment: dis you check your woo commerce product slug or please share the code of view cart file

Comment: Hi,I don't see the slug option

Comment: I found the slug under SEO, and yes the slug is correct. the problem still persists

Comment: http://7c1.529.myftpupload.com/cart/

Comment: please go to your products and then quick edit there will be a options for slug

Comment: also, go to your setting and then Permalinks and set it to default then save it after that reset it to post name again and save it

Comment: The slug is correct and the settings are Default and post name.let me mention that my site is not live yet, it still on a temporary domain name. is that a problem?

Comment: then sorry i need to check code

Comment: How can i give you code?

Comment: you can create a zip of your woo commerce plugin and add it to Dropbox and then send me URL if possible provide WordPress directory too and i request please make hurry it because today is half day hare .

Comment: i am a developer and i understand your feelings well.